# iOS app crash on launch with EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, crash

I'm getting a crash that only happens when the app is launched but I'm not able to find any useful info from the crash logs since it seems that it doesn't have any reference to my code (Xamarin.Forms).

I`m not able to replicate this issue in debug mode, how can I find the related code?

```
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.abc.def [641]


Date/Time:           2020-10-15 01:40:08.4652 -0300
Launch Time:         2020-10-15 01:40:03.0311 -0300
OS Version:          iPhone OS 14.0.1 (18A393)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    6.02.01
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00000001d2c4b95c __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000001edbb79e8 pthread_kill + 212 (pthread.c:1375)
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001b0f1f9b0 __abort + 112 (abort.c:147)
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001b0f1f940 abort + 112 (abort.c:118)
4   ABC.DEF.iOS                 0x00000001060f0ab0 xamarin_initialize.cold.1 + 0
5   ABC.DEF.iOS                 0x00000001060e6440 xamarin_printf + 25945152 (runtime.m:2468)
6   ABC.DEF.iOS                 0x0000000105fa6e44 mono_invoke_unhandled_exception_hook + 24636996 (exception.c:1299)
7   ABC.DEF.iOS                 0x0000000105f3b198 mono_handle_exception_internal + 24195480 (mini-exceptions.c:2778)
8   ABC.DEF.iOS                 0x0000000105f39bbc mono_handle_exception + 24189884 (mini-exceptions.c:3102)
9   ABC.DEF.iOS                 0x0000000105f2f3c8 mono_arm_throw_exception + 24146888 (exceptions-arm64.c:400)
10  ABC.DEF.iOS                 0x0000000104cc036c throw_exception + 172
11  ABC.DEF.iOS                 0x0000000104a8502c System_Runtime_ExceptionServices_ExceptionDispatchInfo_Throw + 44
12  ABC.DEF.iOS                 0x0000000104a8b234 System_Runtime_CompilerServices_AsyncMethodBuilderCore__c__ThrowAsyncb__7_0_object + 84
13  ABC.DEF.iOS                 0x000000010582a28c Foundation_NSAsyncSynchronizationContextDispatcher_Apply + 16786060 (NSAction.cs:178)
14  ABC.DEF.iOS                 0x0000000104c82980 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 272
15  ABC.DEF.iOS                 0x0000000105f4d340 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 24269632 (mini-runtime.c:3164)
16  ABC.DEF.iOS                 0x000000010600da88 mono_runtime_invoke_checked + 25057928 (object.c:3044)
17  ABC.DEF.iOS                 0x000000010601138c mono_runtime_invoke + 25072524 (object.c:3099)
18  ABC.DEF.iOS                 0x00000001048f2dd4 native_to_managed_trampoline_16(objc_object*, objc_selector*, _MonoMethod**, unsigned int) + 830932 (registrar.m:724)
19  ABC.DEF.iOS                 0x00000001048f4280 -[__MonoMac_NSAsyncSynchronizationContextDispatcher xamarinApplySelector] + 836224 (registrar.m:6471)
20  Foundation                      0x00000001a95b4da0 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 184 (NSThread.m:807)
21  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a8255240 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24 (CFRunLoop.c:1967)
22  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a8255140 __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 204 (CFRunLoop.c:2011)
23  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a8254488 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 256 (CFRunLoop.c:2048)
24  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a824ea40 __CFRunLoopRun + 776 (CFRunLoop.c:2925)
25  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001a824e200 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 572 (CFRunLoop.c:3242)
26  GraphicsServices                0x00000001be349598 GSEventRunModal + 160 (GSEvent.c:2259)
27  UIKitCore                       0x00000001aab14004 -[UIApplication _run] + 1052 (UIApplication.m:3270)
28  UIKitCore                       0x00000001aab195d8 UIApplicationMain + 164 (UIApplication.m:4739)
29  ABC.DEF.iOS                 0x0000000105885fec wrapper_managed_to_native_UIKit_UIApplication_UIApplicationMain_int_string___intptr_intptr + 348
30  ABC.DEF.iOS                 0x00000001057d6670 UIKit_UIApplication_Main_string___intptr_intptr + 16442992 (UIApplication.cs:86)
31  ABC.DEF.iOS                 0x00000001057d65f4 UIKit_UIApplication_Main_string___string_string + 16442868 (UIApplication.cs:66)
32  ABC.DEF.iOS                 0x000000010491bff4 ABC_DEF_iOS_Application_Main_string__ + 999412 (/<unknown>:1)
33  ABC.DEF.iOS                 0x0000000104c82980 wrapper_runtime_invoke_object_runtime_invoke_dynamic_intptr_intptr_intptr_intptr + 272
34  ABC.DEF.iOS                 0x0000000105f4d340 mono_jit_runtime_invoke + 24269632 (mini-runtime.c:3164)
35  ABC.DEF.iOS                 0x000000010600da88 mono_runtime_invoke_checked + 25057928 (object.c:3044)
36  ABC.DEF.iOS                 0x0000000106013e94 mono_runtime_exec_main_checked + 25083540 (object.c:0)
37  ABC.DEF.iOS                 0x0000000105f2b1a8 mono_jit_exec + 24129960 (driver.c:1322)
38  ABC.DEF.iOS                 0x00000001060ed700 xamarin_main + 25974528 (monotouch-main.m:0)
39  ABC.DEF.iOS                 0x000000010491b978 main + 997752 (main.m:146)
40  libdyld.dylib                   0x00000001a7f2d598 start + 4
```

Comment: Hi, whether it's a new created Xamarin Forms project? If it's not a complex project, you could share some code of it. Such as `App.xaml.cs` and `MainPage.xaml.cs`.

Comment: I get exactly the same for my Xamarin app. Two out of 700 app installations crashed with this exception on two devices. Where to start looking for what? Users had iPhone OS 14.8 (18H17) and 14.1 (18A8395).